# Making Glowing Background with CSS only

Tags: html, css, radial-gradients

I want to create this background in CSS only.

[image]

I want to do it with CSS to avoid responsive issues.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with only css. But you could try with svg...

Comment: You can have different size of images for the responsive fix

Comment: how about gradients?

Comment: I am struggling to understand how a question whose answer is one line of code can be considered as "too broad". Lack of code in question is not a reason for voting to close as "too broad". This question has a fixed start and end point. Any code that OP provides could only probably to lead to XY problems.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can make use of `radial-gradient` to produce the glow effect. You can change the colors to be inline with the image.

One thing you should note is the browser support for CSS gradients. IE < 10 do not support them. If you need support for older browsers then CSS gradients would not help.

```css
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, rgb(49, 144, 228) 0%, rgb(29, 84, 166) 100%);
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!-- prefix free library included only to avoid vendor prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
```

---

I can't see any extra steps in between but if you are looking for several steps of varying percentages then have a look at the below snippet:

```css
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, rgb(49, 144, 228) 0%, rgb(41, 122, 204) 30%, rgb(29, 84, 166) 70%);
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!-- prefix free library included only to avoid vendor prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Excellent!!! gradients let you display smooth transitions between two or more specified colors

Comment: actually its good solution, but the colors cannot be like I did on photshop.

Comment: body {
 background-image: radial-gradient(circle, white 0%, #1d54a6 100%);
    height: 100vh;
}

Comment: @Mosh: This is only a sample on how to achieve the glow effect. As I mentioned in the answer, you can modify the colors as you wish. The first color should be the innermost one while the second would be the outermost.

Comment: I tried to modify the colors and I still cant see how it will be like my image http://i.stack.imgur.com/J189y.jpg
body {
 background-image: radial-gradient(circle, white 0%, #1d54a6 100%);
    height: 100vh;
}

Comment: I think OP is implying his gradient is not purely color a to b, meaning he might need several steps like colors from a to b for 1st 75% then from b to c for remaining 25%, if thats avhievable can you please update your answer?

Comment: Thanks @Harry, this: body{
 background-image: radial-gradient(circle, rgb(50, 142, 229) 0%, rgb(29, 84, 166) 100%);
     height: 100vh;   
} solved my problem.

Comment: I want to ask one more question. this background goes for <div class="section"></dv> each .section have diagonal edges with this code

.section:before {
 top: -40px;
 -ms-transform: skew(0,2deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skew(0,2deg); /* Safari */
    transform: skew(0,2deg);
}

.section:after {
 bottom: -40px;
 -ms-transform: skew(0,-2deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skew(0,-2deg); /* Safari */
    transform: skew(0,-2deg);
}
https://jsfiddle.net/moshboaron/a9xugp34/

can I somehow avoid the bakground to be "broken" like the glowing is not perfect

Comment: @Mosh: You can apply this to any `div` but splitting the gradient into multiple elements will cause them to not match. If you want them to match then it needs a lot of work.

Comment: @Mosh: It takes effort to match the gradients across mutliple `div`. You can't apply gradient to a non-skewed element + a skewed element and expect them to align just like that. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/a9xugp34/1/) is a different approach that you can try without using extra elements that won't cause the gradient to distort. If you aren't happy with this approach then you must ask a separate question because applying gradient to multiple elements and matching them was not part of the question.

Comment: @Harry perfect simple and short answer. looks smooth :)